# Header contents in implicit block list?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I know that when you `malloc()` space on the heap, you actually take more bytes than requested in order to make room for the header and to allow padding for alignment purposes.

For example, if you call `malloc(41)`, you will get 48 bytes--4 bytes for the header and then 44 bytes of user space.

My question is this: does the header store the size of the entire block (after additional padding and the header space is tacked on), or does it only contain an integer representing the size of the space that the user has access to?

Thanks!

Comment: What is or isn't stored there depends completely on your C library implementation. There is no guarantee that you'll get 48 bytes there, or that there is a header block for each allocation.

Comment: If you want to see what various implementations do, simply go look it up: FreeBSD has jemalloc, Linux has "some malloc" (don't know if it is something special), ...

Comment: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html

Comment: the answer 'depends'  it depends on the implementation.  Typically, the heap is organized as two linked lists.   one linked list is the allocated blocks, the other linked list is the free blocks.   The system functions, like malloc, need to know how big a free block is, so it can determine if there is enough room for the requested allocation in that block.  so the link to the next block and the size of the current block are both available.  Without the size, the malloc and free operations would be very difficult (not fast) and comparisons of many addresses would be needed.